# Repair SDD's filesystem

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, gparted

a friend of mine tried to clone his windows partition with clonezilla to a ssd, as now nothing works at all he asked me for help.

When I try to access the ssd via gparted I get "Input/Output error".

Googleing it brought up lots of posts, mostly suggesting the hardware is broken, which seems unlikly to me as it was a direct cosequence to messing with its partitions.

I also followed some suggetions to try fdisk or testdisk, this and that windows program as well, but it appears to me that the filesystem is damaged in some weird way that these programs cannot detect. Both could not list the ssd.
I don't care about the files on the ssd, i just want it to function normal.

Any suggestion which could help me to get on? Any data/logs required? (Please tell me briefly how to get them)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you want to re-partition it as a UEFI or Legacy drive?

Comment: Is your friend trying to clone his entire existing drive to SSD with the intent of replacing an existing HDD with the SSD? Why would they just copy a single partition. Is there any reason not to reinitialize the SSD? How is the SSD connected? SATA, USB, what? Need more details.

Comment: SSD is connectes via SATA. He tried to only clone windows C:\ but not D:\ as the SSD is smaller than his HDD. I'm not sure which partitions exactly he tried to clone. Furthermore I don't care for now weather it gets re-partitioned as UEFI or Legacy drive, I just need it to get to a state where I can advance on my own, so just give me any.

Comment: Start new comments with `@heynnema` if you want me to see them. My suggestion is to reinitialize the SSD and install a fresh copy of Windows, and then manually copying over your picture/music/etc. from the HDD.